# multiply multiple string values in the same field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with my query to calculate the time when multiple values are selected in the same column.

This is the main table:

| ID | value | time_m |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32221 | book1;book2;book3 | 20 |
| 32222 | book1;book2 | 15 |
| 32233 | book1 | 20 |

My query:

```
WITH CM as (
 
SELECT
    Main.ID as ID,
    case 
       when Main.value= 'book1' then 5
       when Main.value= 'book2' then 8
       when Main.value= 'book3' then 2
       else null 
    end AS numb,
    time_m as time_m
    Main.value 
FROM 
    Main 
) 

SELECT 
   CM.ID
   ,CM.numb
   ,CM.time_m
   ,CM.numb * CM.time_m as resu
   ,CM.value
FROM CM
```

What i get:

| ID | numb | time_m | resu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32221 | Null | 20 | Null |
| 32222 | Null | 15 | Null |
| 32233 | 5 | 20 | 100 |

what I need is similar to this:

| ID | numb | time_m | resu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32221 | 15 | 20 | 300 |
| 32222 | 13 | 15 | 195 |
| 32233 | 5 | 20 | 100 |

how i can do that?

Comment: Why are you storing delimited data in your database is the real question here; why not normalise your design?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use SQL Server 2016+, you simply need to split the stored values using `STRING_SPLIT()`, map the values to the appropriate weights and calculate the result:

```
SELECT m.ID, a.numb, m.time_m, (a.numb * m.time_m) AS resu
FROM main m
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(v.numb)
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(m.[value], ';') s
   JOIN (VALUES 
            ('book1', 5), 
            ('book2', 8), 
            ('book3', 2)
         ) v ([value], numb) ON s.[value] = v.[value]
) a (numb)
```